# Choosing directory when exporting CSV file using php

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-csv

I have the following script that will export a csv file locally on my desktop. Now, when customers update their CSV file i want them to be able to save it to their desktop or downloads folder.
However, how do you select the relevant pathway that will allow each unique customer to export the file.
Potential hurdles, I do not know the username for the customers computer i.e. Users/username/Desktop etc
Is there a function where you can select where you want to export the file? (similar to the save function in Word) Because i am currently using a similar function for importing that allows you to select which file that you want to import?

```
if (!$dbconnect) {
    die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/pathway/ to/save/new.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
FROM Tablename; "
            ;
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if (mysqli_affected_rows($connection) >= 1) {
    $message = "successfully exported!";
} else {
    $message = "Try again";
    $message .= mysqli_error($connection);
}
    echo $message;
}
}
```

Comment: Unless the user has shared their disk with your system, you can't write directly to it, and you can't control where downloads through their web browser should be saved on their computer either.... that's the user's prerogative

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for the reply, I had a feeling that might be the case. Is there a function that is similar to the 'save' function in word where you can select where you want to save the file?

Comment: Not from a web browser, you have no idea what folders might be set up on that user's machine